# What is the best way to present a picture taken?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, photos

In my app, I take some pictures and I display them in thumbnails.

I want to zoom them when user touches them.

What's the best way to do this?
Thanks

**Edit:**
I've considered a modal view.

I don't save the pictures in the gallery. I display them on the screen, that's all.

Comment: Pop up some text telling the user to get a magnifying glass and hover it over the screen area where the thumbnail is showing?

Comment: What options have you considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `UIImagePickerController` you can set it's property `allowsEditing` to `YES` to support scaling taken pictures.

**Edit:** If you already have an Image, please take a look at the [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Hi thanks Florian. That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I considered showing a modal view of the picture. It's a simple thing to do but maybe there is simpler or more elegant.

Comment: So you not want to "zoom" the image, you just want present a bigger version of the image in a modal view?

Comment: exactly, sorry about the "zoom" misuse

Comment: In that case you can use an UIImageView. Add your (big) UIImage to the UIImageView (programmatically) and add it to the UIViewConroller's view as a subview, which I'd do directly in Interface Builder. I hope that helps.

Comment: and to dismiss it, how would you do?

Comment: As you said you'd present the big image in a separate viewController as a modal view. To dismiss a modal view simply call [yourModalViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES].

Comment: but I liked your solution of adding a UIImageView as a subview. I'd like then to dismiss it when a touch is captured. Can I do that?

Comment: As UIImageView is a subclass of UIView, you have to call [<YourUIImageView> removeFromSuperview]. Please read the documentation for UIView.

Comment: works great! I add the UIImageView as a subView. I add a gestureRecognizer to self.view and call a method to do a [<MyUIImageView> removeFromSuperview] Thank you!

Comment: I'm gonna look now for how to setAlpha only on the background and not on the imageView, then work on some animations and it will 100%